# Which criminal investigation TV series has the highest number of episodes based on actual criminal cases?

Tags: most-appearances

What TV crime solving series like Criminal Minds, CSI Miami, NCIS, Law & Order, Criminal Intent, etc. has the highest number of episodes based (however loosely) on actual criminal investigations that were carried out by police?

Note: TV series such as Cops, etc. are not to be included.

Comment: *"Cops"*...or is that too easy? :)  The L&O sagas are likely as many of their stories are *"ripped from the headlines"*.

Comment: Yeah, I'd guess Law & Order too, but this is *really* hard to gauge.

Comment: Almost impossible to gauge as referencing actual cases is a legal minefield....hence the [**disclaimers**](http://rabble.ca/sites/rabble/files/node-images/lo-disclaimer.png) at the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit: This is a new answer.**

It is [Savdhaan India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savdhaan_India). The **total number of episodes is 1687** (as of 12th June 2016).

> Savdhaan India - India Fights Back (English: Caution India! - India Fights Back) is a Hindi-language crime show. It focuses on real-life crime incidents in India and the story of struggle of the victims in order to get justice for their sufferings.

[Crime Patrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_Patrol_(TV_series))

This is a popular TV series based on real crime investigations. **699 episodes** were aired till 20 Aug 16.

> The series, whose motto is "Crime never pays" presents dramatized version of crime cases that occurred in India. Series anchor, Anup Soni suggests the right measures to avert crimes, narrating real-life stories revolving around harassment, kidnapping and murders. The series open the audiences’ minds with these cases making them aware of the dreadful incidences around them.

Answer (score 4):

[America's Most Wanted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America%27s_Most_Wanted) ran for 1,186 episodes and often featured more than one crime.

> The show profiled cases involving the search for and apprehension of
>   fugitives wanted for serious crimes, including murder, rape,
>   kidnapping, child molestation, white-collar crime, organized crime,
>   armed robbery, gang violence, and terrorism, and also many of whom are
>   currently on the FBI Ten Most Wanted Fugitives list. On May 2, 2008,
>   the program's website announced its 1,000th capture; as of March 30,
>   2013, 1,202 people have been captured because of AMW.

Comment: I think the OP was after **fictional** tales *based* on real cases. I agree it's not entirely clear though.

Answer (score 1):

If the answer sought is for fictional treatments of real cases, then "Dragnet". Every episode was based on a real case "names changed to protect the innocent". There were 276 episodes of Dragnet on TV; the same or a few more on radio. Some of the same stories were used on radio and TV.